# How to use async/await while reading a file using readline?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This code is not giving output as I want.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const rl = require("readline");

async function readTwoColumnFile() {

    console.log('reading file');

    // (C) READ LINE-BY-LINE INTO ARRAY
    const reader = rl.createInterface({
      input: fs.createReadStream("index.js")
    });

    reader.on("line", (row) => {
      //some code
    });

    // (D) DONE - FULL ARRAY
    reader.on("close", async () => {
      // some code
      console.log('reading complete')
      res = 'Hello World!'
      return res
    });
}

async function run(){
    const res = await readTwoColumnFile()
    console.log('data' , res)
}

run()
```

Here the line `console.log('data', res)` is executing without `res` being initialized so when I run this code my output is coming

```
reading file
data undefined
reading complete
```

Instead of

```
reading file
reading complete
data Hello World!
```

So how can I wait for `res` to get executed after initilazation?

Comment: Just because you made the callbacks async function, doesn't make this async code. Use the [Promises API](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#promises-api).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return a new Promise instance in `readTwoColumnFile`.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const rl = require("readline");

function readTwoColumnFile() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('reading file');

    // (C) READ LINE-BY-LINE INTO ARRAY
    const reader = rl.createInterface({
      input: fs.createReadStream("index.js")
    });

    reader.on("line", (row) => {
      //some code
    });

    reader.on('error', reject);

    // (D) DONE - FULL ARRAY
    reader.on("close", async () => {
      // some code
      console.log('reading complete')
      res = 'Hello World!'
      resolve(res);
    });
  });
    
}

async function run(){
    const res = await readTwoColumnFile()
    console.log('data' , res)
}

run()
```

Comment: Also, there is no event called `line`. You should use the `data` event (https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#event-data)

Comment: You're welcome @samsonmarandi. @martensi, there is an event called `line` in Readline API (https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/readline.html#event-line).